# Does one Lie subgroup imply the existence of another in this situation?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let $n,p,r \in {\mathbb Z}$ with $p \geq 2$, $r \geq 2$ and $n = p + r$.

Let $G \subseteq SU\left( n\right)$ be a Lie group and let $S \subset G$ be the subset of all elements in $G$ of the form $g = g_1 \oplus g_2$ where $g_1 \in SU\left( p\right)$, $g_2 \in SU\left( r\right)$.

Let $G_1 \subseteq SU\left( p\right)$ be the set of all $g_1$'s in $S$, i.e. ${G_1} = \bigcup\limits_{{g_1} \oplus {g_2} \in S} {\left\{ {{g_1}} \right\}} $.

Similarly, let $G_2 \subseteq SU\left( r\right)$ be the set of all $g_2$'s in $S$, i.e. ${G_2} = \bigcup\limits_{{g_1} \oplus {g_2} \in S} {\left\{ {{g_2}} \right\}} $.

If $G_1$ is a Lie group, does it follow that $G_2$ must also be a Lie group $\forall\; p,r$? If so, how would I go about proving this? If not, what would be a counterexample?

Does the answer change if $G_1 = SU\left( p\right)$?

I'm not sure how to proceed and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does not $e_p \oplus g_2$ inject $G_2$ into $G$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that $e_p\oplus g_2$ may not be an element of $S$ for all $g_2$. As it turns out, I found a quick proof that the answer to my question is "yes".